# Windows with Python 3.5: What to do since pip won't work with dependency_links?

Tags: pip, python-3.5, setuptools, setup.py

I need to install a specific public package for one of my projects. I tried to do:

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(
    name             = 'aaa',
    install_requires = ['hyperas==0.3']
    dependency_links = ['git+https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas.git#egg=hyperas-0.3']
)
```

But gave up because I couldn't get it to work and it was being deprecated. What is the correct way to tell pip to download a package from a particular url rather than from PyPi?

The url I need is https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas, rather than https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hyperas. Is this possible?